# Is there a way to use ansi-C quoting in fish shell?

Tags: fish, ansi-escape

In bash/zsh, I'm able to introduce color with sed using the command below
`echo "Foo" | sed $'s/.*/\e[33m&\e[33m/'`

I'm able to do this in bash and zshell using [ANSI quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html).

I haven't found out how to do this in fish shell yet, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "Foo" | sed 's/.*/'\e'[33m&'\e'[33m/'
```

or better

```
echo "Foo" | sed 's/.*/'(set_color yellow)'&/'
```

or

```
set -l yellow (set_color yellow)
echo "Foo" | sed "s/.*/$yellow&/"
```

Fish does not have ANSI quoting because it allows the escapes outside of quotes - the equivalent of `$'\e'` is just `\e`.

The `set_color` builtin to emit color sequences is preferred, though.